# $\int_1^\infty\frac 1{\ln x}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

How do I show that $\int_1^\infty\frac 1{\ln x}dx$ diverges? I'm thinking to break up the integral into two parts, say, over $[1,2]$ and $[2,\infty)$, but how do I integrate the integrand?

I'm stumped partly because the author claims part (f) is proved similarly as part (a)/(b). But how can this be!? Part (f) is so much more non-trivial than (a)/(b).

[image]

Comment: On the one hand, you have a non-integrable singularity at $1$, on the other, the integrand is larger than $\frac1x$, and the divergence of the latter shows the divergence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** For appropiate values of $x$ it holds that $x\ge \log (x)$ and $\dfrac 1{\log (x)}\ge \dfrac 1 x$.

Comment: On the other side, a similar hint: $\frac{1}{\log x}>\frac{1}{x-1}$.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that 
$$\frac{1}{\ln x}\geq\frac{1}{x\ln x}\,\;\forall x\geq1$$
and 
$$\int_1^a \frac{1}{x\ln x}dx=\ln(\ln a)\to+\infty$$
so your integral is divergent.

Answer (score 4):

Apply the *[Limit Comparison Test](http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/2924/cal78.pdf)* for improper integrals to the functions $f(x)=\frac{1}{\log x}$ and 
$g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Since

- by L'Hôpital 
  \begin{equation*}
  \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }
  \frac{x}{\log x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{1/x}=\infty ,
   \end{equation*}
- at the singularity of $f(x)$, i.e. at the lower limit of integration
  \begin{equation*}
  \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+ }\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+ }
  \frac{x}{\log x}=\infty ,
   \end{equation*}
- and by (a) 
  \begin{equation*}
  \int_{1}^{\infty }g(x)\, dx=\int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{x}dx
  \end{equation*}
  *diverges*, *then so does* 
  \begin{equation*}
  \int_{1}^{\infty }f(x)\, dx=\int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\log x}dx.
  \end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. I had been looking for a formal statement of the comparison test for improper integrals. Speaking of which, are you merely offering your answer as an alternative to the more straightforward direct comparison test?

Comment: @Ryan This was an alternative to the direct comparison test (DCT), but sometimes it is easier to find the limit than to deal directly with the inequality of the DCT.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $x = \expo{z}$:
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x\over \ln\pars{x}}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{z}\,\dd z \over z}\quad\mbox{diverges !!!}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice!! %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%